# How do I get a variable in a URL, but when the URL is saved in a PHP variable?

Tags: php

```
$url= "justfwalk.it?uid=12";
```

How can I get the variable "uid" from this string?

Is there is an easier method than looking for it's position and trimming the string?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @Brad `Note:

This function doesn't work with relative URLs.`

Comment: @Neal, but it is trivial to concatenate a protocol and hostname to the front to use this function.  Or, split on `?` and use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use parseurl

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/'.$url;
print_r(parse_url($url));
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

How about [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) and [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str)?

```
<?php
$params = array();
$url= "justfwalk.it?uid=12";
$url_parts = parse_url( $url);
parse_str( $url_parts['query'], $params);
echo $params['uid']; // Outputs 12
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/q9JT5k)

Answer (score 0):

```
list($html, $get) = explode('?', $url);
$get = explode('=', $get);
print_r($get);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode("=", $url);
$uid = $parts[1];
```