# RegEx to grab url out of another url

Tags: php, regex, url, urlencode

String to pull from : `http:\/\/c.ypcdn.com\/2\/c\/rtd?vrid=357c99c36bd7ed631eda2e43fc9e30f8&rid=283d465f-f63b-4b0d-90b0-be6c12ed7617&ptid=943aw4l8qj&ypid=11720135&lid=194823099&tl=6&lsrc=SP&dest=http%3A%2F%2FCleanation.com`

RegEx I have used before: `www\..*?\.\w{2,5}`

However the above RegEx will only grab the URL if it has a "www". in it. If I take out the "www." of the RegEx it justs grabs the c.ypcdn.com. I want to grab the Cleanation.com at the end of the string.

Needs to be dynamic so it can grab any url that doesn't have a "www." out of that url.

Comment: Is it always the "dest" parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a variable in a URL, but when the URL is saved in a PHP variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156283/how-do-i-get-a-variable-in-a-url-but-when-the-url-is-saved-in-a-php-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and then [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/parse_str) on the returned `query` index to get it?

edit: example:

```
$url= "http://c.ypcdn.com/2/c/rtd?vrid=357c99c36bd7ed631eda2e43fc9e30f8&rid=283d465f-f63b-4b0d-90b0-be6c12ed7617&ptid=943aw4l8qj&ypid=11720135&lid=194823099&tl=6&lsrc=SP&dest=http%3A%2F%2FCleanation.com";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query,$params);
echo $params['dest'];
```

Comment: Wow that works a lot better. Thanks. I'm still very new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If this is always the `dest` parameter, you can grab it with something like:

```
"dest=https?%3A%2F%2F([^?&]+?)"
```

If its aways the last parameter, you can grab it with:

```
"dest=https?%3A%2F%2F(.+)$"
```